# Obj-C Assignment Warning With Init Method

Tags: objective-c

I have an init method defined as:

```
- (id)initWithX:(float)inX AndY:(float)inY
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        [self setX:inX andY:inY];
    }

    return self;    
}
```

When I use this method like this:

```
MyObject* myObject = [[MyObject alloc] initWithX:0.0 AndY:0.0];
```

I get a warning saying: "warning: initialization from distinct Objective-C type"

But interestingly, if I change the "AndY:" to "andY:" in the method signature, the warning goes away.

Why would this be happening? Surely the naming of my method shouldn't affect its return type??

---

After a little more investigation, changing the method name use use the lowercase 'andY' didn't make the warning disappear. I cleaned all targets, and rebuilt and the warning didn't show. But it came back after another recompile. Odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be something else at work here, and I'm not entirely sure what.

I read the cocoa guidelines and the naming methods topics, where it says not to use and to link keywords, thanks to Toon Van Acker for the link.

I removed the "andY:" exchanging it simply for "y:" and the warning has disappeared, regardless of how many cleans and rebuilds I do.

I still don't understand why this would cause the compiler to throw a warning though. Even though it goes against the naming methods guidelines, the method signatures matched in the header and implementation...

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit vague without the full code context, but I'll try to answer your question.

The naming of a method selector should not affect its return type. However, if the method names are mismatched (for example, it's called -initWithX:andY: in the @interface, but -initWithX:AndY: in the @implementation) you can run into strange problems. Incidentally, the Cocoa convention for multi-part selectors is to begin each fragment with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Also, incidently, Apple's coding guidelines from upon using "and" to connect arguments as in andY:(int)intY

"Don’t use “and” to link keywords that are attributes of the receiver."

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html

Comment: An excellent point! I'd forgotten that, but it's great advice.

Comment: This was the first thing I checked, but it's not the problem. The declaration in the interface matches the definition in the implementation perfectly.

The method signature used in the interface is:

    - (id)initWithX:(float)x AndY:(float)y;

Answer (score 2):

Did you declare it with a lowercase "and" in your .h file?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect, like others have mentioned, that you've named the methods differently in the class interface delcaration (the `@interface` block, probably in a .h file) and the method implementation (inside the `@implementation` block). When the Objective-C compiler encounters an unknown method, it assumes that input arguments are of type `id` (an object reference). So, when it encounters the method using the `AndY:` naming, it doesn't recognize the method (selectors are case sensitive) and assumes the inputs should be type `id`. Since you're passing inputs of type `float`, you get the warning. Obviously when the method is recognized and the compiler knows the inputs are type `float`, you don't get the warning.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that if you had named the method incorrectly you'd have got a different warning (initWithX:AndY: method not found).

What is the declaration in the header file returning? Declaring the method as

```
- (NSObject*)initWithX:(float)inX AndY:(float)inY;
```

for example, would give you this warning.

Comment: the signature returns an id. - (id)initWithX:(float)x andY:(float)y;